# Как настроить камеру CineMachine в unity, чтобы она не выходила за коллайдеры(управление от 3го лица)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотел сделать через Cinemachine Collider, но почему-то нет такого компонента. Теперь не знаю что и делать.[image: Скрин того, что у меня есть]